# PHP Sessions keep timing out after 24 minutes... session.gc_maxlifetime set to 90000

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-timeout

I can't figure out why my PHP sessions are timing out after 24 minutes even after I set session.gc_maxlifetime to a very high amount.

I specifically went into my /tmp folder to look at the session data files being created. Just as you would expect with PHP's garbage collecting, every so often the older files would be deleted. Every time, it seemed to be the files that were > 24 minutes old. This seems strange because the default of session.gc_maxlifetime is 1440 seconds (24 minutes). But I changed that variable, and nothing else in php.ini is set to 1440. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: did you restart the server? I think some problem have with firefox new version. it not destroy session.

Comment: @Narek nope.... Is this going to be a major facepalm moment? Will PHP not recognize the change in gc_maxlifetime until Apache is restarted?

Comment: @jonjammamsm as I know without restart no one change will apply.

Comment: It did not help. I restarted the server, but the same problem persists.

Comment: Just to be sure that PHP has the right settings, could you please look up the `session.gc_maxlifetime` parameter in a phpinfo page and check if it has the right value?

Comment: @Carsten I did check that. It's definitely set properly. That's why this is so confusing. My first impulse was that maybe the php.ini didn't get saved and it's still reverting to default, but I can't find any active reference to 1440 or 24 minutes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand... 
If you don't want to have files older than 24 minute, then you don't need to change anything.

Otherwise, just extend the 1440 value to the one you need and restart Apache.

Which value did you assign to the `session.gc_maxlifetime`?